# How to calculate difference of two arrays with same value at second position

Tags: javascript

I've got a git diff output string parsed to this array, which gives me all changed dependencies in a package.json file:

```
const data = [
    [ '-', '@date-io/moment', '1.3.13', '1', '3', '13' ],
    [ '+', '@date-io/moment', '1.3.14', '1', '3', '14' ],
    [ '-', '@emotion/react', '11.7.0', '11', '7', '0' ],
    [ '-', '@emotion/styled', '11.6.0', '11', '6', '0' ],
    [ '+', '@emotion/react', '11.8.2', '11', '8', '2' ],
    [ '+', '@emotion/styled', '11.8.1', '11', '8', '1' ]
]
```

The first element (`+`/ `-`) shows me if this change was added or deleted. The second element is the package name (this is the element, which connects two arrays), and the next fields give me the version.
Now I need to iterate this array to find out which kind of version change has been made for each package. So the output should be:

```
{
    '@date-io/moment': 'patch',
    '@emotion/react': 'minor',
    '@emotion/styled': 'minor'
}
```

I tried to get all packages by doing

```
const result = {}
data.forEach(d => {
    result[d[1]] = bump // how to calculate `bump`?
})
```

But this doesn't handle `+` and `-` and it doesn't calculate the type of version bump.

Comment: How do you recognize that the change is patch or minor or anything else?

Comment: @masoud https://semver.org/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `Array.prototype.reduce` to reduce you can reduce the array into an object and for each package use `Array.prototype.find` to find the corresponding change. Then you can compare the versions and determine its change.

```js
const data = [
    [ '-', '@date-io/moment', '1.3.13', '1', '3', '13' ],
    [ '+', '@date-io/moment', '1.3.14', '1', '3', '14' ],
    [ '-', '@emotion/react', '11.7.0', '11', '7', '0' ],
    [ '-', '@emotion/styled', '11.6.0', '11', '6', '0' ],
    [ '+', '@emotion/react', '11.8.2', '11', '8', '2' ],
    [ '+', '@emotion/styled', '11.8.1', '11', '8', '1' ]
];

const changes = data.reduce((t, [type, name, , major, minor, patch], i, arr) => {
    if (type === "+") {
        const match = arr
          .find(([type, pName]) => type === "-" && pName === name);
        if (!match) {
          return t; // handle no match here
        }
        const [, , , pMajor, pMinor, pPatch] = match;
        return {
            ...t,
            [name]: pMajor !== major ? "major" :
                pMinor !== minor ? "minor" :
                "patch"
        }
    }
    return t;
}, {});

console.log(changes);
```

Comment: What about if there is only one package element, which means it has been just added or deleted?

Comment: @user3142695 then you should specify that in your question

Comment: I'm sorry, I just recognized this, as I tried to run your code on my data. I do get the error `TypeError: undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))`.

Comment: @user3142695 You asked about the difference of two arrays. This sounds like a different question.

Comment: @Undo My comment was for user3142695. You correctly answered the question and I upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 2):

- Create a `Map` of all subtractions
- Loop over all the additions and reduce it to the desired object using the map.

```js
const data = [
  ["-", "@date-io/moment", "1.3.13", "1", "3", "13"],
  ["+", "@date-io/moment", "1.3.14", "1", "3", "14"],
  ["-", "@emotion/react", "11.7.0", "11", "7", "0"],
  ["-", "@emotion/styled", "11.6.0", "11", "6", "0"],
  ["+", "@emotion/react", "11.8.2", "11", "8", "2"],
  ["+", "@emotion/styled", "11.8.1", "11", "8", "1"],
];

const subMap = new Map(data.filter((d) => d[0] === "-").map((d) => [d[1], d]));

const additions = data.filter((d) => d[0] === "+");

const updates = additions.reduce((updates, addition) => {
  const pkgName = addition[1];
  const [maj, min, patch] = addition.slice(-3);
  const [oldMaj, oldMin, oldPatch] = subMap.get(pkgName).slice(-3);

  if (maj === oldMaj && min === oldMin && patch >= oldPatch) {
    updates[pkgName] = "patch";
  } else if (maj === oldMaj && min >= oldMin) {
    updates[pkgName] = "minor";
  } else {
    updates[pkgName] = "major";
  }

  return updates;
}, {});

console.log(updates);
```